# Derivatives and limits

Tags: calculus

Why did the author ask to evaluate the limit by converting into a derivative ? the solutions manual just converted it without explaining why. I really don't get it.
[image]

Comment: @amWhy thomas' calculus early transcendentals book asked me.....

Comment: I assume the exercises are designed to help you learn the definition of derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\dfrac{x^{50}-1}{x-1}$$

If you just plug in $x=1$ then it becomes indeterminate form.

So, you need to use [L'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

By L'Hopital's rule
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\dfrac{50x^{49}}{1}=50$$

Similarly for the $68$ question.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is there another method of solving these limits ? Because I haven't taken L'Hopital's rule yet.

Comment: Refer to the definition of *derivatives*. Convince yourself that this limit is just $f'(1)$ for $f(x) = x^{50}$ defined nearby $x = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just the observation that if you put
$$f(x) = x^{50} $$ then by definition of derivative:
$$\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} = f'(x_0)$$

Put $x_0= 1$. Now solve the second limit similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Elementary way to do the questions.

**67**. 
$$
\frac {x^{50}-1}{x-1} = \sum_0^{49} x^j \xrightarrow{x \to 1} 50. 
$$

**68**. Let $t = x^{1/9}$. Then 
$$
\frac {x^{2/9}-1}{x+1} = \frac {t^2 - 1}{t^9+1} = \frac {(t+1)(t-1)}{(t+1)(t^8-t^7+t^6 -\dots - t +1)} = \frac {t-1}{t^8-t^7 +t^6 - \dots - t +1} \xrightarrow{t \to -1} -\frac 29,
$$

thus the limit is $-2/9$.